# How to rewrite URL addresses using struts2?

Tags: jsp, url, struts2, tiles

I am expecting my code to reformat the URL and show them as following (with / )

```
 http://www.example.com/myProject/Profile/view.action
 http://www.example.com/myProject/Profile/edit.action
```

but it shows them as following (with _ )

```
http://www.example.com/myProject/Profile_view.action
http://www.example.com/myProject/Profile_edit.action
```

To make that, I changed the " _ " to "/" in my struts.xml file but it does not work

```
<action name="Profile/*" method="{1}" class="com.controller.Profile">
      <result name="view" tiles="viewProfile">viewProfile</result>
       <result name="edit" tiles="editProfile">editProfile</result>
  </action>
```

I am calling that using following code

```
 <a href="Profile/view.action" >Profile</a>
```

**Please let me know if there is any other method to implement it.**

Comment: After changing the _ to / did you restart the web application? Anyways you shouldn't be able to use slashes in action names unless you set struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames to true. You did this?

Comment: I don't understand what is it a correct URL, Is the URL format of the addresses is incorrect or do you need a specification with to formatting URLs?

Comment: @RomanC, I changed the word to rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your really want to separate your actions with slash, you should use `NAMESPACE`, try this:

```
<package name="profile" extends="struts-default" namespace="/Profile">
    <action name="*" method="{1}" class="com.controller.Profile">
      <result name="view" tiles="viewProfile">viewProfile</result>
      <result name="edit" tiles="editProfile">editProfile</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

And if you are trying to use parameters on the url, you should consider use

```
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
```

on your Struts 2 configuration file.

Regards to the [Wildcart Mapping](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html) document, you can also do this:

```
    <action name="**" method="{1}" class="com.controller.Profile">
      <result name="view" tiles="viewProfile">viewProfile</result>
      <result name="edit" tiles="editProfile">editProfile</result>
    </action>
```

`** matches zero or more characters including the slash ('/') character.` You can also find this on the  [Wildcart Mapping](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html) document.

You should think about what you *really* want first, *then* do the configuration and implementation.

In your case, Struts 2 thinks that you have slash on your action, regards to the [Action Configuration](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/action-configuration.html)

> **Action Names With Slashes** 
>   If your action names have slashes in them
>   (for example,  `<action name="admin/home" class="tutorial.Admin"/>`) you
>   need to specifically  allow slashes in your action names via a
>   constant in the struts.xml file by  specifying 
>   `<constant> name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>`.
>   See JIRA Issue WW-1383 for discussion as there are side effects to  setting
>   this property to true.
>
> **Action Names with Dots and Dashes** 
>   Although action naming is pretty
>   flexible, one should pay attention when  using dots (eg. `create.user`)
>   and/or dashes (eg. `my-action`). While the dot  notation has no known
>   side effects at this time, the dash notation will  cause problems with
>   the generated JavaScript for certain tags and themes.  Use with
>   caution, and always try to use camelcase action names  (eg.
>   `createUser`) or underscores (eg. `my_action`).

So Struts 2 will convert your slash to an underscore.

Comment: thanks it works but with a minor problem as following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886855/how-to-change-my-code-to-implement-url-reqriting-correctly

Answer (score 1):

why are you calling your action like

`<a href="Profile/view.action" >Profile</a>`

however you can achieve this using

```
<a href="view.action" >Profile</a>
```

and made changes in your xml

```
<action name="view.action" method="{1}" class="com.controller.Profile">
      <result name="view" tiles="viewProfile">viewProfile</result>
       <result name="edit" tiles="editProfile">editProfile</result>
</action>
```

you are not allowed to use wildcards here in your mapping for **method="{1}"**,because in your action you have not specified anything.And  if you really want to use wildcards then specify a method name in your action like this

```
<a href="YOURMETHODNAMEview.action" >Profile</a>
```

**and in your xml**

```
 <action name="*view.action" method="{1}" class="com.controller.Profile">
          <result name="view" tiles="viewProfile">viewProfile</result>
           <result name="edit" tiles="editProfile">editProfile</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: I suppose it is used to remove the extension not reformatting the URL.

Answer (score 0):

By default, struts does not allow / in action name. You can achieve what you want by using namespace or modify the struts config to allow dashes in action.

1.To use namespace, define another package with namespace "/Profile":

```
<package name="profile" extends="struts-default" namespace="/Profile">
<action name="*" method="{1}" class="com.controller.Profile">
  <result name="view" tiles="viewProfile">viewProfile</result>
  <result name="edit" tiles="editProfile">editProfile</result>
</action>
......
</package>
```

This method is good if you want to group many actions under the same namespace.

2.To allow dashes in action, you have 2 options, to define constants in struts.xml like below:

```
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
```

or to define it in struts.properties:

```
struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames=true
struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace=false
```

After that you can use this in struts.xml:

```
<action name="Profile/*" method="{1}" class="com.controller.Profile">
  <result name="view" tiles="viewProfile">viewProfile</result>
   <result name="edit" tiles="editProfile">editProfile</result>
</action>
```