# How to change my code to implement url-rewriting correctly using tiles and struts2

Tags: jsp, url-rewriting, struts2

I am using the follwoing code to rewrite my URL. everytime I click on the Profile link it works but adds EXTRA Profile/view to the end of address.

```
http://www.example.com/myProject/Profile/view.action
```

first time I click on view it changes it to

```
 http://www.example.com/myProject/Profile/Profile/view.action
```

after that if I click the view again it will be (everytime I click it addes a /Profile to the address)

```
  http://localhost:8080/myProject/Profile/Profile/Profile/view.action
```

link

```
  <a href="<s:url action="Profile/view"/>" >Profile</a>
```

struts.xml

```
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
    </result-types>

      <action name="index">
        <result type="tiles">content</result>
    </action>

 </package>

  <package name="Profile" extends="default" namespace="/Profile">
  <action name = "*" method="{1}" class="com.myproject.Profile">
    <result name="View" type="tiles">Profile</result>
            <result name="Edit" type="tiles">Edit</result>
</action>
    </package>
```

**the problem is that everytime I click on view it does not remove the address and add the profile/view to the end of it. It just change the address from www.example.com/myproject/profile/view to www.example.com/myproject/profile/profile/view**

Comment: I don't understand how re-writing comes in to this. What's the issue?

Comment: Hi dave, I followed your answer in previous question but as explained first time it works but i I click on view further everytime it adds an extra Profile/view to the end of address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to say without the package declaration, but it looks like you're getting an extra namespace in the action because you're specifying it in the `<s:url>` tag as part of the action instead of using the `namespace` attribute.

If the current action is part of the Profile namespace it won't be added. If it isn't, it will. Using the `namespace` attribute handles it automatically, so you don't have to think about it.

---

Edited to reflect the completely unrelated question.

You are extending the `struts-default` package, which has no knowledge of the `tiles` result type. You need to extend *your* default, which *does* include the `tiles` result type, or `tiles-default` (or whatever it's called, I don't recall).

Comment: @DanielMorgan As I suspected. You should also *start* the namespace with a slash, not end it, although I don't know if that would affect behavior or not.

Comment: changed it to defauls but still adds extra /Profile

Comment: @DanielMorgan Did you make the change I suggested?

Comment: yes I extends default, it works but everytime I click on view it adds  extra /profile

Comment: the problem is that everytime I click on view it does not remove the address and add the profile/view to the end of it but just change the address from profile/view to profile/profile/view

Comment: @DanielMorgan Was that the only suggestion I made?